# Posting Array Of Objects to Jersey REST API

Tags: java, arrays, json, rest, jersey

I am trying to post an array of JSON Objects to a Jersey Resource but getting the following exception. 
This is how my array of JSON Object Looks Like:

```
var jsonArray = 
[
{"certItemId":"8adbb3ba5029829101502a0b29d00030","challengerComments":"C1"},
{"certItemId":"8adbb3ba5029829101502a0b29d00031","challengerComments":"C2"} ]
```

AJAX Request:

```
$.ajax({

        type : 'POST',
        url : url,
        data:{itemsChallenged:jsonArray},
        success: function(result){
        },

        error: function(error){
          location.replace("exception.jsf");
          console.log(error);
        },
        complete: function(){

        }
});
```

Java Method:

```
@POST
@Path("test")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response challengeWorkItem(@QueryParam("itemsChallenged") Object[] itemsChallenged) throws GeneralException{


}
```

Getting Following Error:

```
SEVERE: The following errors and warnings have been detected with resource and/or provider classes:
      SEVERE: Missing dependency for method public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.demo.rest.DirectReportChallenge.challengeWorkItem(java.lang.Object[]) throws sailpoint.tools.GeneralException at parameter at index 0
      SEVERE: Method, public javax.ws.rs.core.Response com.demo.rest.DirectReportChallenge.challengeWorkItem(java.lang.Object[]) throws sailpoint.tools.GeneralException, annotated with POST of resource, class com.demo.rest.DirectReportChallenge, is not recognized as valid resource method.
    Oct 4, 2015 1:21:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
    SEVERE: StandardWrapper.Throwable
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:489)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:857)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
    Oct 4, 2015 1:21:05 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
    SEVERE: Allocate exception for servlet JAX-RS AEXP REST Servlet
    com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors$ErrorMessagesException
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processErrorMessages(Errors.java:170)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.postProcess(Errors.java:136)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.inject.Errors.processWithErrors(Errors.java:199)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:770)
        at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.initiate(WebApplicationImpl.java:765)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.initiate(ServletContainer.java:489)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer$InternalWebComponent.initiate(ServletContainer.java:319)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.load(WebComponent.java:609)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.init(WebComponent.java:210)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:374)
        at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:557)
        at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:160)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1266)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1185)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.allocate(StandardWrapper.java:857)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:136)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
        at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
        at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:999)
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:565)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: It seems that you expect the collection in a query string and send them in a body.

Comment: @Opal I Just need to send the collection data to the service. Is there any other way i can send it?

Comment: It seems that you just need to remove this annotation `@QueryParam("itemsChallenged")`.